# parse xhtml in python 2.6

Tags: python, xhtml

xml.etree.ElementTree.parse is choking on my xhtml file. I saw somewhere that lxml can handle html. Can someone tell me the documented way to parse, and then alter, xhtml? I want to add some javascript to xhtml on the fly.

Comment: What is ‘choking’? Is the document not well-formed XML? Is it using the HTML-specific entities that a non-DTD-reading parser will fail to resolve?

Comment: By 'choking' I mean that when I try to parse my xhtml file like this:

html = myElementTree.parse(myXHTMLFile)

The application throws the following exception:

undefined entity &nbsp;: line 16, column 164

I've run into this before in other languages. The &nbsp; is a valid character in html, but not in xml, as you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? It handles documents that aren't well formed and I've found it pretty good.

Comment: Yes - I used in an extractor for data from an xhtml website and it seemed to manage fine. I'm not sure how easy it is to use BeautifulSoup to then edit the document as I've only ever been interested in extraction, but it will handle the extraction part.